# Deleting log groups and streams with a terraform destroy

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I see that Terraform does not delete log groups and streams (AWS provider) after performing the destroy operation. I know that it might be needed for some points, but in my case it is not and it makes a little mess in the log groups. I have to build and destroy quite often and removing it manually is not comfortable.

Is there any way to enable deleting these groups and streams on destroy action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you manage them in terraform then terraform will also destroy them.

The reason they stick around often is that a lot of the log groups are created automatically by the service, e.g. Lambda. And if you do not explicitly create the log group first then terraform does not know about and therefore cannot destroy them.

Solution: create the `aws_cloudwatch_log_group` in your terraform config AND set proper explicit `depends_on` relations between the resources that needs the log group and the log group itself. Otherwise you might get into a situation where during a `terraform apply` the lambda gets created, eventually invoked, creates the log group and (if you are unlucky) only then does terraform try to create the log group and will then fail due to it already existing. Or the other way around during deletion, terraform deleting the log group first, lambda getting invoked one last time, recreating the log group, then getting deleted itself and the log group remaining because terraform did already delete *its* managed log group.

The log streams in the log group will be automatically deleted alongside the log group itself. Terraform does not know about the streams at all and neither can it, because they are only created during the lifetime of the infrastructure.